# boot strap grid css horizontal stacking

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to solve a css problem with bootstrap 'possibly' if we can stack rows with different height like this picture bellow (column has equal width but different height from one another)

[horizontal stacking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZKXo.png)

Comment: What your'e asking for is called a Masonry Layout. Bootstrap v4 [seems to offer](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#card-columns) a built-in way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a concept of Masonry. I will suggest to follow the links below. Following this link, you will be able to understand the concept of Masonry.

```
http://masonry.desandro.com/
```

Below link will help you to understand the CSS and HTML required for making this Masonry layout.

```
http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html
```

Also I am providing the link where you can edit this Masonry Layout. Hope this help you to solve your problem.

```
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/JFpeg
```